# How to check if response body has data?

Tags: java, testng

Im new to TestNG and I'm trying to test if the respone body has data. Right now, the JSON body gives back these datas, if I run the `http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/loadEvents` on `POSTMAN`.

```
   [ {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Fradi vs UTE",
            "type": "Football Match",
            "start": [
                2022,
                5,
                29,
                8,
                47,
                54,
                383000000
            ],
            "end": [
                2022,
                5,
                29,
                10,
                47,
                54,
                383000000
            ]
        }, ... ]
```

Now I should test the same `http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/loadEvents` API endpoint with TestNG, but how should I do it? I tried this:

```
@Test
public void testGetEvents(){
    given().when().get("http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/loadEvents").then().statusCode(200);
}
```

It gives back 200 OK response, however I would like to test if the response body contains JSON data, such as `id, title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option will be is to create object representation of your response, like `MyEvent.java`. For fast-creating such classes use online tools like [this](https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo).

`MyEvent.java`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyEvent {
    private Integer id;
    private String title;
    private String type;
    private List<Integer> start;
    private List<Integer> end;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Integer> getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(List<Integer> start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public List<Integer> getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(List<Integer> end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

And test will look like:

```
@Test
public void testGetEvents() {
    /*
        I had to use online service to simulate your response, so please uncomment the line:
        List<MyEvent> events = given().when().get("http://localhost:8080/sportsbetting-web/loadEvents")
    */
    List<MyEvent> events = given().when().get("https://sportsbetting.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path")
            .then().statusCode(200)
            .extract().as(new TypeRef<List<MyEvent>>() {});

    System.out.println("Total amount of events: " + events.size());

    System.out.println("For each event - show if 'id' or 'title' exist");
    int eventCounter = 0;
    for (MyEvent event : events) {
        System.out.println("Processing event number " + (++eventCounter));
        if (event.getId() != null) {
            System.out.println("Id " + event.getId());
        }
        if (event.getTitle() != null) {
            System.out.println("Title " + event.getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

Result of test execution:
[image]

Notes:

1. Additional dependencies (in example below I am using gradle syntax, but same idea will be applied for maven):

   ```
   implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.13.3'
   implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.13.3'
   implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.13.3'
   ```
2. Instead of writing multiple getters/setters in `MyEvent` class - better use Lombok library (google it), and just add `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations right under `MyEvent` class. This is how Lombok can be added to gradle project:

   ```
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
   ```